# PHP Code running very slow although there are only 17,257 rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 17,257 rows in MySQL (Size: 6.6 MiB), whenever I am running my PHP code, it's too slow and takes more than 30 minutes to open the webpage. I read somewhere to change mysqli_fetch_array to fetch_assoc, but still I can't see any change. Any suggestions?
Initially I had a complex code, so I changed it to the one present below, but still I can't observe any change.

```
 $md=$db->query("SELECT MDid,MD_FullName FROM MDList");

        while($row=$md->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $mdid=$row['MDid'];
            $mdname=$row['MD_FullName'];

            $distinct_filenames=$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(FileName) AS Files FROM InitialLog WHERE MDid='$mdid' AND FileName NOT LIKE '%Patient Names%'");

            while($row2=$distinct_filenames->fetch_assoc())

            {
                $filename=$row2['Files'];

                $finalquery=$db->query("SELECT LinesCount,CharCount,WordCount,PageCount FROM InitialLog WHERE FileName='$filename' AND (DateLastSaved>='$firstdate' AND DateLastSaved<='$presentdate') AND MONTH(DateLastSaved) = (SELECT MIN(MONTH(DateLastSaved)) FROM InitialLog WHERE FileName='$filename') ORDER BY DAY(DateLastSaved) DESC LIMIT 1");


                while($row3=$finalquery->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $linecount=$linecount+$row3['LinesCount'];
                    $charcount=$charcount+$row3['CharCount'];
                    $wordcount=$wordcount+$row3['WordCount'];
                    $pagecount=$pagecount+$row3['PageCount'];
                 }

           }
```

What I wan't to achieve through queries is:

Tables:

1. MDList (Consist of MD ids of all the MDs)
2. InitialLog (Consist of FileNames of each MDid and the counts)

My first query chooses each MDid one by one from the table MDlist.

Second query takes distinct file names from InitialLogs table for that specific MD chosen from first query (File names can be same)

Third query returns various counts of each distinct filename of the specific MD. The count is returned normally if one file exists of that name, if there are more files present, so it returns the count of such filename, which exists in the first month and the last day of that first month, like if it exists in 01-01-2016,22-01-2016,23-02-2016, so it returns that count which is in the row (22-01-2016), that is the last day of the first month.

In the end I sum all the counts returned for each MD.

Comment: Check the indexes on your database tables

Comment: Learn to use JOINs in your database queries

Comment: Just count the total number of queries you send to database. A lot of fast queries (assuming they're really fast) will still need a lot of time to run.

Comment: Essentially what Mark is telling you is that you should never be running queries inside of a loop. Look up INNER JOIN to join tables to eachother. Every single time you call `->query` is has to send that query to the server (over network), wait for the server to execute the query, wait for the server to send back a response and then back to your client.

Comment: have you tried on different server or are you just working on localhost?

Comment: @DineshBhojvani on different server, it is not taking 30 minutes, but still not too fast

Comment: @MariumMalik you must study about joins, you are running so many queries, first you fetch data MDList, then in a loop you fetch data for another table and in another loop within your exisitng loop you are running another select query.

Comment: @ShaktiGoyal yes I am reading a tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You are making a zillion SQL queries.

Well, somewhere in the region of `<Number of MD Results> * <Number of distinct filenames>` SQL queries.

Since you are just adding up some stats, it will likely to be more efficient to create a single query that sums up the correct values to start with.

Check out SUM() and JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you should avoid executing queries in loops at (pretty much) any cost. Your SGBD engine is designed to handle data aggregation, join, exclusions and such.

It should be better this way, but please read notes below about why it's not a good idea. It's a direct transcription from your query logic which might be rewritten for better performances and safety.

```
SELECT 
    sum(log.LinesCount), sum(log.CharCount), 
    sum(log.WordCount), sum(log.PageCount) 
FROM InitialLog log
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT l2.FileName, l2.MD_id 
    FROM InitialLog l2
    WHERE l2.FileName NOT LIKE '%Patient Names%'
) filtered_name
ON filtered_name.FileName=log.FileName
INNER JOIN MDList md
ON filtered_name.MD_id = md.MDid
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(MONTH(l3.DateLastSaved)) as minmonth
    FROM InitialLog l3
    WHERE l3.FileName='$filename'
) lastSaved     
ON lastSaved.minmonth = log.DateLastSaved
WHERE 
    log.DateLastSaved>='$firstdate' 
    AND log.DateLastSaved<='$presentdate'
ORDER BY 
    DAY(log.DateLastSaved) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

First, `NOT LIKE '%whatever%'` is usually a bad idea as it requires to perform a full scan; it would be much more efficient with a `JOIN` and a nullity test or use a view or another way to avoid this scan altogether (adding a column, etc.). At least, try to avoid wildcards (`%`) at start of pattern.

Next, you're using string concatenation to inject parameters into your query, that's bad. You should use prepared queries with real parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Finally, your should consider altering your dates (or add column updated by trigger, set up a view, whatever) to avoid inconsistent comparaisons.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately your query returns me null result

Comment: @MariumMalik Please update your question with sample data and expected behaviour. As you may imagine, reverse-engIneering three nested queries not knowing what they're supposed to do isn't an easy job :)